# Application of Farkas Lemma

Tags: optimization, systems-of-equations, linear-programming

> Let $A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n }, b \in \mathbb R^m$ and $0 \neq c \in \mathbb R^m$. Prove: Either the system $Ax = c$ or the system $A^T y = 0, c^T y = 1$ has a solution.

Looks a bit like Farkas Lemma but the $c^T y = 1$ confuses me. Can someone give me a hint?

I know two versions of Farkas Lemma:

$$ \text{Either} \quad Ax = b, x \geq 0 \quad \text{or} \quad A^T y \geq 0, b^T y < 0 \quad \text{is solvable.}$$

$$ \text{Either} \quad Ax \leq b \quad \text{or} \quad A^T y = 0, y \geq 0, b^T y < 0 \quad \text{is solvable.}$$

Comment: Which variant of Farkas Lemma are you allowed to use?

Comment: @RobPratt I added it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: To get a nonnegative variable into the mix, replace a free variable with a difference of nonnegative variables.

Comment: I don‘t understand how this helps me with "translating" $c^T y = 1$?